# Javascript crash sometimes and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I building website using following script. Sometime this javascript crash sometimes not. Weird thing is when I add alert box at third line after sliderLeft define, script never crash. Someone please help with this.
I am using same function twice for different output.

Even I remove Second similar function I am still getting error. Please help me with this.

```
$(window).load(function() {             
    var sliderLeft=$('#thumbScroller .container').position();
    //alert(sliderLeft);
 //   padding=$('#outer_container').css('paddingRight').replace("px", "");
    var sliderWidth=$(window).width()
    $('#thumbScroller').css('width',sliderWidth);
    var totalContent=0;
    $('#thumbScroller .content').each(function () {
        totalContent+=$(this).innerWidth();
        $('#thumbScroller .container').css('width',totalContent);
    });
    //alert(sliderLeft);
    $('#thumbScroller').mousemove(function(e){
        if($('#thumbScroller  .container').width()>sliderWidth){
            var mouseCoords=(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var mousePercentX=mouseCoords/sliderWidth;
            var destX=-(((totalContent-(sliderWidth))-sliderWidth)*(mousePercentX));
            var thePosA=mouseCoords-destX;
            var thePosB=destX-mouseCoords;
            var animSpeed=600; //ease amount
            var easeType='easeOutCirc';
            if(mouseCoords==destX){
                $('#thumbScroller .container').stop();
            }
            else if(mouseCoords>destX){
                //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',-thePosA); //without easing
                $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: -thePosA}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
            }
            else if(mouseCoords<destX){
                //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',thePosB); //without easing
                $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: thePosB}, animSpeed,easeType); //with easing
            }
        }
    });
    $('#thumbScroller  .thumb').each(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.6);
    });
    var fadeSpeed=200;
    $('#thumbScroller .thumb').hover(
    function(){ //mouse over
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 1);
    },
    function(){ //mouse out
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeSpeed, 0.6);
    }
);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    //$('#thumbScroller .container').css('left',sliderLeft); //without easing
    $('#thumbScroller .container').stop().animate({left: sliderLeft}, 400,'easeOutCirc'); //with easing
    $('#thumbScroller').css('width',$(window).width());
    sliderWidth=$(window).width();
});
```

I just remove second function as per suggestion, but still not work
removed few lines and script crash and doesn't display any error

Comment: Crash how? It causes the browser to crash, or it doesn't run at all?

Comment: are all browsers crashing, or any one in particular?

Comment: You can remove `sliderLeft`, it's not being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: thanks badzoke it nothing wrong with script, problem is different thankx for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 `$(window).load(function() {...});` function definitions.

Try combing them into 1 `$(window).load(function() {...});` call.

Comment: I just remove second function to find bug and still getting error and getting error on this line  padding=$('#outer_container').css('paddingRight').replace("px", ""); I define outer_container id in css as well as padding-right but still not under stand where am i wrong

Comment: Here is error

TypeError: $(...).css(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

    padding=$('#outer_container').css('paddingRight').replace("px", "");

I define outer_container id in css as well as padding-right but still not under stand where am i wrong

Comment: I dont think i getting error in this line , look at the updated script in question and getting unknown error

Comment: Can you put your html, css and javascript into http://jsfiddle.net/? Recreate the problem and share it with us.

Comment: sorry I can't upload html, css and javascript in jsfiddle.net because I am using 6 different javascript for my project.

Comment: Do you have this code running live on the internet somewhere that you can share?

Comment: I found the problem, Actual problem is I am not loading page properly. check this live example I just add simple script in home about page. www.simpleclick.com.au Please note:- I am using third party source code....

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea...

Hard to say without seeing the problem (as said by 3dgoo try put your code into jsfiddle.net) but Are you sure your code executes when dom is ready ?

It'd explained that the 'alert' you put in your code 'solve' the problem by giving it time to finish loading.

Comment: thankx for replay, you may be right because I am using $(window).load function for above script. Originally I am loading page through ajax so i get www.example.com./#/test url. My friend point me this mistake. so I am going to use trigger() function to call window function. And sorry I can't upload html, css and javascript in jsfiddle.net because I am using 6 different javascript for my project. If you know any good example for trigger() function share with me. thanks

Comment: No example for using trigger() but you can also :
 - test your elements (ex :$('#thumbScroller')) before using them 
 - use $(document).ready(function () {...});